# is there any linqish way to save user form data - Re factoring my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a simple form which takes a user data and save it to database. while it is working fine but seems pretty repetitive.. i am not sure if i can turn my code in some way that it checks for user input and save it in DB.

here is my code..

```
public void SaveUserData()
      {
            MWCompetitionContestantsDetails user = new MWCompetitionContestantsDetails();
            MWCompetitionsEntryDetails entry = new MWCompetitionsEntryDetails();

            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(firstNameText.Value))
                  user.FirstName = firstNameText.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameText.Value))
                  user.LastName = lastNameText.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(emailText.Value))
                  user.UserEmailAddress = emailText.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(address1Text.Value))
                  user.Address1= address1Text.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(address2Text.Value))
                  user.Address2 = address2Text.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(cityText.Value))
                  user.City = cityText.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(provinceText.Value))
                  user.Province= provinceText.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(postCodeText.Value))
                  user.PostalCode = postCodeText.Value;
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(countryText.SelectedItem.Text))
                  user.Country = countryText.SelectedItem.Text;

            user.Save();
      }

      public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
      {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);

            return value.Equals(default(T));
      }
```

rather then looking for IsNullOrEmpty(data) on every fields, are there any suggestion to improve my code using Linq or anything..

your time much appreciated...

Comment: With your code, what happens if the user actually wants to remove the address line 2, for example?

Comment: if they dont enter any values in address line 2, values does not get entered in DB.. and if they want to remove address line 2 later after first creation, i can update the table ..have not implemented that code yet

Comment: I guess my question is then why the isnullorempty checks - they don't seem necessary to me?  If you take them out, then that's your update code implemented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to say that I like `oniant`'s and `Adil Mammadov`'s solutions as they are deadly simple.
However I've already written code of fancy-shmancy approach I like to use in similar situations and I'd like to share it:

```
      class Save<T> : ISave
    {
        private readonly System.Action<T> _assignValue;
        private readonly System.Func<T> _getValue;

        public void Do()
        {
            T value = _getValue();
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _assignValue(value);
            }
        }

        public static Save<T> Value<T>(System.Func<T> getValue, System.Action<T> assignValue)
        {
            return new Save<T>(getValue, assignValue);
        }

        private Save(System.Func<T> getValue, System.Action<T> assignValue)
        {
            _getValue = getValue;
            _assignValue = assignValue;
        }

        private static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);

            return value.Equals(default(T));
        }
    }

    internal interface ISave
    {
        void Do();
    }

    public static void SaveUserData()
    {
        MWCompetitionContestantsDetails user = new MWCompetitionContestantsDetails();
        MWCompetitionsEntryDetails entry = new MWCompetitionsEntryDetails();

        new List<ISave>
        {
            Save<string>.Value( () => firstNameText.Value, x => user.FirstName = x),
            Save<string>.Value( () => lastNameText.Value, x => user.LastName = x),              
            Save<int>.Value( () => age.Value, x => user.Age = x),// int's supported :)              
            // etc
        }
        .ForEach(x => x.Do());
        user.Save();
    }
```

Comment: I tried with your approach and found out compilation error in your DO()..it says Deligate System.Action<T> has some invalid argument in _assignValue(value)

Comment: what's version of your .NET?

Comment: Still it works fine for me with .net 3.5. I've updated the code a bit  - made all the types to be defined via namespace.

Comment: still not able to figure out what is wrong... still getting the same error

Comment: ohhh!!! got it man.. thats because i was defining the class as static... my bad.. now works great...

Comment: 1 query, does it support datetime and bool if i want to insert through Save(T)

Answer (score 2):

You can check If null or empty at the setter of your properties:

```
public class MWCompetitionContestantsDetails
{
    private string _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                this._firstName = value;
            }
        }
    }       

    .........

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
              return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);

        return value.Equals(default(T));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your properties are string, you may use the object initialization :

```
MWCompetitionContestantsDetails user = new MWCompetitionContestantsDetails(){
        FirstName = firstNameText.Value,
        LastName = lastNameText.Value,
        UserEmailAddress = emailText.Value,
        Address1= address1Text.Value,
        Address2 = address2Text.Value,
        City = cityText.Value,
        Province= provinceText.Value,
        PostalCode = postCodeText.Value,
        Country = countryText.SelectedItem.Text
};
user.Save();
```